# How to properly decode and browse a JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to decode the following JSON:

```
{"urls":{"id":"1","url":"http://www.someUrl.com"}}
```

The problem is that may code only works when there's more than one entry in 'urls'

```
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
foreach($value->urls as $urlField) {
    $url = trim($urlField->url);
    $id = trim($urlField->id);
}
```

so

```
{"urls":{"id":"1","url":"http://www.someUrl.com"}}
```

isn't parsed properly but

```
{"urls":[{"id":"1","url":"http://www.someUrl.com"}, {"id":"2","url":"http://www.someUrl2.com"}]}
```

is

When there's a single 'urls' entry the $urlField value in a loop is a string which contains the 'http://www.someUrl.com' value. 
Any idea why?

Comment: `json_decode` works fine..

Comment: what do you expect as result ?

Comment: I expect to be able to browse and extract the content of each field, which doesn't' work when there's a single value in 'urls'

Comment: may be your `file_get_content` is doing the problem for you, Your single json decode result is `stdClass Object ( [urls] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [url] => http://www.someUrl.com ) )`

Comment: so how can I handle this case and extract those values in that case ?

Comment: Passing the second line in a jsonparser I have this error : `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name at line 1 column 52 of the JSON data` but nothing more

Comment: Your second example is not valid json, it will not decode / it does not result in an array or object.

Comment: This was a typo. I fixed it. The json string decodes without any issue.

Comment: So make sure the `urls` key in the first example is an array as well or test if it is an array in your code before you use it...

Comment: I cannot change the json as I do not create it. I'm just looking for a solution to handle those 2 cases

Comment: @user1026605 now check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

When your json contain 2 or more data then it create an extra array so it is different from the first one.
Now here i do for both the conditions.

```
$json = '{"urls":[{"id":"1","url":"http://www.someUrl.com"}, {"id":"2","url":"http://www.someUrl2.com"}]}';

$arr = json_decode($json);

foreach($arr as $key => $urlField){
    if(count($arr->urls) > 1){
        foreach($urlField as $key2 => $urlField2){
            echo $urlField[$key2]->id;  //echo $urlField2->id;
            echo $urlField[$key2]->url; //echo $urlField2->url;
        }
    }else{
        echo $urlField->id;
        echo $urlField->url;    
    }   
}
```

**Result:**

```
1
http://www.someUrl.com
2
http://www.someUrl2.com
```

Check and let me know if it work for you or not.